# self-recovering ssh tunnel over non-100% connection

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I want to setup permanent ssh-tunnel for port forwarding to machine behind firewall. The connection is between university network (very reliable) and commercial microwave metropolitan connection to a company (outages for a few minutes/several months max), and I want the connection to recover automatically after it fails.

I recall ther were some ssh wrappers featuring heartbeat failure detection, but I am curiously not able to google those up now. Which of them would you recommend?

Comment: stick it in a for loop with a sleep command ? :-)

Comment: @Sirex: Why sleep? Plus, this would not detect that data are not getting through.

Answer (score 7):

Meanwhile I found [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) which looks like exactly what I need.